# How do I create a date using data from string list?

Tags: python

In the data I have a list of strings that looks more less like that:

`date = ["year=2019", "numberofmonth=5", "numberofday=7"]`

Unfortunately this is the quality of the data I got and it is not possible to change it. 
I would like to create the date (2019-05-07) using just the let's say values after "=" sign. Could you please help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's an extra `"`? `"numberofday"=7"`, I'm guessing `"numberofday=7"``?

Comment: sorry, that's my mistake, there should not be extra "

Comment: Are those month numbers 0-indexed? what have you tried? Are you trying to create a date object or a string?

Comment: Are they always in the same order inside the list?

Comment: Actually it is like plain text. As it is part of json, I firstly thought I may treat this as an object in json, but when I displayed the data I got the thing I presented above.

Comment: As I checked, they're always in the same order.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), and [`str.zfill`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill) to create a date string which you can parse later:

```
date = ["year=2019", "numberofmonth=5", "numberofday=7"]

date_str = '-'.join(d.split('=')[1].zfill(2) for d in date)

print(date_str)
```

Output:

```
2019-05-07
```

Comment: It is pretty easy! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the values from it like:

```
>>> import re
>>> date = ["year=2019", "numberofmonth=5", "numberofday=7"]
>>> ''.join(re.findall(r'\d+-?','-'.join(date)))
'2019-5-7'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could do the trick.

```
import re
date = ["year=2019", "numberofmonth=5", "numberofday=7"]
date_string = ''.join(re.findall(r'\d+-?','-'.join(date)))
print(date_string)
```